# How to use a generic method in Java to CRUD any table in MySQL, using Hibernate with Criteria, passing Table name and/or fields as a parameter?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate in a Struts2 and Hibernate project and I would like to perform all the operations in the database using the criteria.

The problem is I have several tables and when I want to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE a row for example I have to create a method for every table. Is there any way to make it more generic passing the name of the table or class and/or the object I want to modify?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has developed a version of it [here](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/). This has been done using generics, you can do it too using Generics.

Comment: Thank you @Zeus ! That was helpful. I don't have now to worry about the amount of the table I have.